# Filling empty dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I have trouble filling an empty dictionary in Python

I declare the dictionary as follow :

```
my_dict = {}
```

I want to fill it with different key and differents values one at a time. 
I would like to have at the end something like :

```
{"1":(1,2,3,4),"2":(4,5,6,7),"3":(8,9,10,11),"4":(12,13,14,15)}
```

Therefore I tried to do it as follow :

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
         my_dict[str(i)].append(j)
```

But I have the following error at the first loop :

> KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>       2 for i in range(4):
>       3     for j in range(4):
>       ----> 4          my_dict[str(i)].append(j)
>       KeyError: '0'

I have a much more complicated for loop in my code but I tried to be the more general as possible to help other who might have a similar problem.
At the end I would like to have different size's value for each key.

If you have any idea why it does not work and how to fix it please feel free to answer.

**EDIT**

Sorry for the confusion, I wanted something like the following :

```
{'1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
             '2': [5, 6, 7, 8],
             '3': [9, 10, 11, 12],
             '4': [13, 14, 15, 16]})
```

Comment: First thing, dictionary does not have append() method. And, you have to assign the value to a corresponding key as: my_dict[key] = value.

Comment: `"1":(1,2,3,4),"2":(4,5,6,7)` should be `"1":(1,2,3,4),"2":(5,6,7,8)` and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. You cannot append to a tuple. Tuples are immutable.
2. You cannot append to a dictionary value which has not yet been defined for a specific key. This is the cause of your `KeyError`.

These issues can be alleviated by using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
         my_dict[str(i)].append(j)

print(my_dict)

defaultdict(list,
            {'0': [0, 1, 2, 3],
             '1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
             '2': [0, 1, 2, 3],
             '3': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
```

Closer to your desired output, you will need to redefine your `range` objects:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range((i-1)*4+1, i*4+1):
         my_dict[str(i)].append(j)

print(my_dict)

defaultdict(list,
            {'1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
             '2': [5, 6, 7, 8],
             '3': [9, 10, 11, 12],
             '4': [13, 14, 15, 16]})
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was trying to do !

Answer (score 1):

You can create this `dict`, with a list as values, using a little dict comprehension:

```
my_dict = {str(i+1): [j for j in range((i*4)+1, (i+1)*4+1)] for i in range(4)}
```

EDIT: OP realized he wanted a list, not a tuple.